# CISCO ASR1004 Total Active Translations

Tags: snmp, cisco, nat, oid

I am trying to get the total number of active NAT sessions on a CISCO ASR1004 device.

Currently, I only know to get this information via logging into the console and running 'show ip nat statistices'.

In order to add this to a monitoring system (cacti and icinga), I created a script that does the same, but it's a nasty hack and sometimes (one time in 8 or 10) stalls out and sits waiting for nothing.

If someone can either direct me to an SNMP item for this stat (I can't seem to find one in all the MIBS I have) or a way to make my scripts more stable, I would appreciate it very much :D

---

#### active_nats.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
output=$(/opt/mon/all_nat_stats.sh $1 | grep "Total active translations:" | awk '{print $4}')
echo -n "$output"
```

---

#### all_nat_stats.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 0 0]
set timeout -1

spawn ssh monitor@$ipaddr show ip nat statistics
match_max 100000
expect -timeout 2 "yes/no" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "<password>\r"
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/asr1000/mib/guide/asr1mib.pdf

"The MODULE-IDENTITY for the CISCO-IETF-NAT-MIB is ciscoIetfNatMIB, and its top-level OID is 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.10.77 (iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.cisco.ciscoExperiment.ciscoIetfNatMIB)."

Maybe you could poke around there, I didn't see anything that said 'total active nat session count' though.